# How check two tables content in two instance are same or not?

Tags: mysql, compare, md5

### The Problem Description

I have two similar databases (MySQL) on two machines with a table with exactly the same structure. The order of  data insertion can be different, but the final table contents must be the same except for the order of rows.

### Table structur

| # | Column | Type | Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | old_id | int(11) | unsigned, primary key, not null |
| 2 | new_id | int(11) | unsigned, primary key, not null |

### The *unsuccessful* solution

I tried this query to get the MD5 checksum of all records to be able to compare the result of each database:

```sql
SELECT 
    MD5(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`new_id`,':', `old_id`)))
FROM `maptable`
ORDER BY `new_id`,`old_id`
```

But there is a problem here. The checksum does not change even when I filter some rows. For example:

```sql
SELECT 
    MD5(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`new_id`, `old_id`)))
FROM `maptable`
WHERE mod(`new_id`, 2) = 0
ORDER BY `new_id`,`old_id`
```

### Questions

1. Why does it not work? Is that because of the size of the `GROUP_CONCAT()` result? (the tables have about one million rows)
2. Do you have any **simple query** to get a checksum of the table content to check if the table content is the same? (I do not want to use Python, PHP, or any other programs to fetch the rows and make checksum.)

Comment: Have you tried [CHECKSUM TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/checksum-table.html)?

Comment: Yes, but it is not enough good and limited to tables. and does not work for views or two query result and so on.

Comment: You don't have to checksum views, because they don't store anything. Only checksum base tables. What's the point of checksumming query results? What are you comparing them to?